# Plotting CSV data with python: List index out of range

Tags: python, file, csv, indexing, plot

I'm trying to make a plot from some data but I get an index out of range error even though the data has 2 columns. Here's the code:

```html
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def getColumn(filename, column):
    results = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter='\t')
    return [result[column] for result in results]

wavelength = getColumn('Bb69.dat.fix',0)
flux = getColumn('Bb69.dat.fix',1)

plt.figure('Bb69')
plt.xlabel('Wavelength (angstrom)')
plt.ylabel('flux (erg/cm^2/s/angstrom)')
plt.plot(wavelength,flux)
plt.show()
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "SP12.py", line 14, in <module>

    flux = getColumn('Bb69.dat.fix',1)

  File "SP12.py", line 11, in getColumn

    return [result[column] for result in results]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def getColumn(filename, column):
    results = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter='\t')
    return [result[column] for result in results]
```

It is possible, that not all elements of `results` always contain 2 elements as awaited. For example the csv-file contains empty lines.

Change the last line of the `getColumn` method to:

```
    return [result[column] for result in results if len(result) > column]
```

which is however a risk, because it may return longer lists for lower `column` if some of the lines do not contain enough fields.

Even better would be:

```
wavelength = []
flux = []

with open('Bb69.dat.fix') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'):
        if len(row) >= 2:
            wavelength.append(float(row[0]))
            flux.append(float(row[1]))
```

This guarantees the same length for `wavelength` and `flux`.

Comment: But the file doesn't contain any empty lines, and when I add this I get an valueerror that x and y must have the same dimension(?)

Comment: @StevendeRond - then the file has some line(s) with a single element. Check my updated answer.

Comment: If I use this the wavelength and flux are both empty. The file does have zeros in the 2nd column and the rest are very small numbers so maby that's the problem?

Comment: Empty? You can add a few `print`s around to see what the code does. Oh and we (both of us) forgot to convert the strings to floats. Now it has been updated.

Comment: What does `print row` between the `for` and `if` lines print?

Comment: Exactly what I want it to print